# Change border color of a SearchView

Tags: android, android-view, searchview, android-styles, android-search

I want to change a border color of my searchview . Right now its coming transparent . I tried giving styling to it but nothing working .

**SearchView.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        style="@style/CitySearchView"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="CitySearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
        <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/blue_search_bar</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/labelColorHighligh</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/backgroud_user</item>
        <item name="queryBackground">@color/labelColorHighligh</item>

    </style>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Create drawable file `background.xml` with this content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:padding="12dp"
       android:shape="rectangle" >
       <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
       <stroke
           android:width="0.3dp"
           android:color="#797979" />
   </shape>
   ```
2. Add the drawable to the background:

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
       android:background="@drawable/background"
       android:id="@+id/searchView"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:layout_width="300dp" />
   ```